# printf field width : bytes or chars?

Tags: c, unicode, glibc

The printf/fprintf/sprintf family supports 
a width field in its format specifier. I have a doubt
for the case of (non-wide) char arrays arguments:

Is the width field supposed to mean bytes or characters?

What is the (correct-de facto) behaviour if the char array
corresponds to (say) a raw UTF-8 string? 
(I know that normally I should use some wide char type, 
that's not the point)

For example, in

```
char s[] = "ni\xc3\xb1o";  // utf8 encoded "niño"
fprintf(f,"%5s",s);
```

Is that function supposed to try to ouput just 5 bytes 
(plain C chars) (and you take responsability of misalignments
or other problems if two bytes results in a textual characters) ?

Or is it supposed to try to compute the length of "textual characters"
of the array? (decodifying it... according to the current locale?)
(in the example, this would amount to find out that the string has
4 unicode chars, so it would add a space for padding).

**UPDATE**: I agree with the answers, it is logical that the printf family doesnt
distinguish plain C chars from bytes. The problem is my glibc doest not seem
to fully respect this notion, if the locale has been set previously, and if 
one has the (today most used) LANG/LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

Case in point:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
main () {
        char * locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); /* I have LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" */
        char s[] = {'n','i', 0xc3,0xb1,'o',0}; /* "niño" in utf8: 5 bytes, 4 unicode chars */
        printf("|%*s|\n",6,s); /* this should pad a blank - works ok*/
        printf("|%.*s|\n",4,s); /* this should eat a char - works ok */
        char s3[] = {'A',0xb1,'B',0}; /* this is not valid UTF8 */
        printf("|%s|\n",s3);     /* print raw chars - ok */
        printf("|%.*s|\n",15,s3);     /* panics (why???) */
}
```

So, even when a non-POSIX-C locale has been set, still *printf* seems to have the right notion for counting width: bytes (c plain chars) and not unicode chars. That's fine. However, when given a char array that is not decodable in his locale, it silently panics (it aborts - nothing is printed after the first '|' - without error messages)... only if it needs to count some width. I dont understand why it even tries to decode the string from utf-8, when it doesn need/have to. Is this a bug in glibc ?

Tested with glibc 2.11.1 (Fedora 12)  (also glibc 2.3.6)

Note: it's not related to terminal display issues - you can check the output by piping to od : `$ ./a.out | od -t cx1` Here's my output:

```
0000000   |       n   i 303 261   o   |  \n   |   n   i 303 261   |  \n
         7c  20  6e  69  c3  b1  6f  7c  0a  7c  6e  69  c3  b1  7c  0a
0000020   |   A 261   B   |  \n   |
         7c  41  b1  42  7c  0a  7c
```

**UPDATE 2 (May 2015)**: This questionable behaviour [has been fixed](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6530) in newer versions of glibc (from 2.17, it seems). With `glibc-2.17-21.fc19` it works ok for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will result in five bytes being output. And five chars. In ISO C, there is no distinction between chars and bytes. Bytes are *not necessarily* 8 bits, instead being defined as the width of a char.

The ISO term for an 8-bit value is an octet.

Your "niño" string is actually five characters wide in terms of the C environment (sans the null terminator, of course). If only four symbols show up on your terminal, that's almost certainly a function of the terminal, not C's output functions.

I'm not saying a C implementation couldn't handle Unicode. It could quite easily do UTF-32 if CHAR_BITS was defined as 32. UTF-8 would be harder since it's a variable length encoding but there are ways around almost any problem :-)

---

Based on your update, it seems like you might have a problem. However, I'm not seeing your described behaviour in my setup with the same locale settings. In my case, I'm getting the same output in those last two `printf` statements.

If your setup is just stopping output after the first `|` (I assume that's what you mean by abort but, if you meant the whole program aborts, that's *much* more serious), I would raise the issue with [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html) (try your particular distributions bug procedures first). You've done all the important work such as producing a minimal test case so someone should even be happy to run that against the latest version if your distribution doesn't quite get there (most don't).

---

As an aside, I'm not sure what you meant by checking the `od` output. On my system, I get:

```
pax> ./qq | od -t cx1
0000000   |       n   i 303 261   o   |  \n   |   n   i 303 261   |  \n
         7c  20  6e  69  c3  b1  6f  7c  0a  7c  6e  69  c3  b1  7c  0a
0000020   |   A 261   B   |  \n   |   A 261   B   |  \n
         7c  41  b1  42  7c  0a  7c  41  b1  42  7c  0a
0000034
```

so you can see the output stream contains the UTF-8, meaning that it's the terminal program which must interpret this. C/glibc isn't modifying the output at all, so maybe I just misunderstood what you were trying to say.

Although I've *just* realised you may be saying that *your* `od` output has only the starting bar on that line as well (unlike mine which appears to not have the problem), meaning that it *is* something wrong within C/glibc, not something wrong with the terminal silently dropping the characters (in all honesty, I would expect the terminal to drop either the whole line or just the offending character (i.e., output `|A`) - the fact that you're just getting `|` seems to preclude a terminal problem). Please clarify that.

Comment: Have you got UTF-8 as LC_TYPE ? Anyway, I added my output. 
And I'm thinking I have just traced the problem to this glib issue (not a bug... they say) http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=649 - See the last comment. That's nasty...

Comment: @leonbloy: you could add quotation from the bug comment as an answer for others easier to find.

Comment: Ok, I posted my findings in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Bytes (chars).  There is no built-in support for Unicode semantics.  You can imagine it as resulting in at least 5 calls to [fputc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputc/).

Answer (score 1):

The original question (bytes or chars?) was rightly answered by several people: both according to the spec and the *glibc* implementation, the width  (or precision) in the *printf* C function **counts bytes** (or plain C chars, which are the same thing). So, `fprintf(f,"%5s",s)` in my first example, means definitely *"try to output at least **5 bytes** (plain chars) from the array s -if not enough, pad with blanks"*.

It does not matter whether the string (in my example, of byte-length 5) represents text encoded in -say- UTF8 and if fact contains 4 "textual (unicode) characters". To *printf()*, internally, it just has 5 (plain) C chars, and that's what counts.

Ok, this seems crystal clear. But it doesn't explain my other problem. Then we must be missing something.

Searching in glibc bug-tracker, I found some related (rather old) issues - I was not the first one caught by this... feature:

http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6530

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=208308

http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=649

This quote, from the last link, is specially relevant here:

```
ISO C99 requires for %.*s to only write complete characters that fit below the
precision number of bytes.  If you are using say UTF-8 locale, but ISO-8859-1
characters as shown in the input file you provided, some of the strings are
not valid UTF-8 strings, therefore sprintf fails with -1 because of the
encoding error. That's not a bug in glibc.
```

Whether it is a bug (perhaps in interpretation or in the ISO spec itself) is debatable.
But what *glibc* is doing is clear now.

Recall my problematic statement: `printf("|%.*s|\n",15,s3)` . Here, glibc must find out if the length of `s3` is greater than 15 and, if so, truncate it. For computing this length  it doesn't need to mess with encodings at all. But, if it must be truncated, *glibc* strives to be careful: if it just keeps the first 15 bytes, it could potentially break a multibyte character in half, and hence produce an invalid text output (I'd be ok with that - but glibc sticks to its curious ISO C99 interpretation).
So, it unfortunately *needs to decode the char array, using the environment locale, to find out where are the real characters boundaries*. Hence, for example, if LC_TYPE says UTF-8 and the array is not a valid UTF-8 bytes sequence, it aborts (not so bad, because then `printf` returns -1 ; not so well, because it prints part of the string anyway, so it's difficult to recover cleanly).

Apparently only in this case, when a precision is specified for a string and there is possibility of truncation, *glibc* needs to mix some Unicode semantics with the plain-chars/bytes semantics. Quite ugly, IMO, but so it is.

*Update*: Notice that this behaviour is relevant not only for the case of invalid original encodings, but also for invalid codes after the truncation. For example:

```
char s[] = "ni\xc3\xb1o";  /* "niño" in UTF8: 5 bytes, 4 unicode chars */
printf("|%.3s|",s); /* would cut the double-byte UTF8 char in two */
```

Thi truncates the field to 2 bytes, not 3, because it refuses to output an invalid UTF8 string:

```
$ ./a.out
|ni|
$ ./a.out | od -t cx1
0000000   |   n   i   |  \n
        7c 6e 69 7c 0a
```

UPDATE (May 2015) This (IMO) questionable behaviour has been changed (fixed) in newer versions of glib. See main question.

Comment: The `glibc` (not `glib`) behavior you describe and cite the comment on is an intentional bug. C99 **does not** mandate or allow the implementation to cut the string shorter than the precision to avoid writing "partial characters". Even though the *format string* must be a valid multibyte character string, `%s` is specified purely in terms of bytes, never multibyte characters. The text that the `glibc` developers wrongly cite as specifying this buggy behavior is from a different section describing the behavior of `%ls` (for `wchar_t` strings), not `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

What you've found is a bug in glibc. Unfortunately it's an intentional one which the developers refuse to fix. See here for a description:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/uclibc/Glibc_vs_uClibc_Differences.txt

Answer (score 0):

To be portable, convert the string using `mbstowcs` and print it using `printf( "%6ls", wchar_ptr )`.

`%ls` is the specifier for a wide string according to [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fprintf.html).

There is no "de-facto" standard. Typically, I would expect `stdout` to accept UTF-8 if the OS and locale have been configured to treat it as a UTF-8 file, but I would expect `printf` to be ignorant of multibyte encoding because it isn't defined in those terms.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mbstowcs unless you also make sure that wchar_t is at-least 32 bits long.
else you'll likely end up with UTF-16 which has all disadvantages of UTF-8 and
all the disadvantages of UTF-32.

I'm not saying avoid mbstowcs I just saying don't let windows programmers use it.

It might be simpler to use iconv to convert to UTF-32.

Comment: `mbstowcs` is specified to behave as multiple calls to `mbtowc`, and the latter *cannot* output UTF-16 surrogates due to the way the API works. If Windows' `mbstowcs` outputs UTF-16, it's non-conformant. A conformant implementation using 16-bit `wchar_t` is inherently limited to the BMP.